# How to use VBA on Aspen Hysys?

Tags: control-engineering, chemical-engineering, dynamics, process-engineering, signal-processing

I am trying to write a program on Aspen Hysys. Hysys has a script manager to write scripts using Visual Basics for Applications syntax. Having no background in VBA, I'd like some help to:

1. Import the current value of a controller's output signal (OP).
2. Compare it with it's previous value (in a dynamic simulation).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe you should ask this in https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: you should probably look on programming specific sites rather than engineering. stackoverflow is a good place to start, and the documentation for any software packages you are using (Aspen Hysys).

Comment: Oh alright! Thanks for the advice! I'll check stackoverflow and I'll search for more documentation even though it is sparsely available.
-OP

Comment: Seriously to stack overflow? You know HYSYS uses its variables on its own accord right? First you need to identify the name of the variable on HYSYS language, then do the handling and then use script manager to specify the value. It isn't easy but StackOverflow does not know the answer